# Use of quotes for angularjs- directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm practicing writing AngularJS app using modules and embedded HTML. Does anyone know why the source of the `ng-include` directive below requires single quotes inside double quotes, while the source for the `<script>` files only needs one type of quotes?

I know for a fact that `ng-include` directive doesn't work if I only use one type of quotes. But I don't know why this is the case.

Thank you!

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Angularjs practice
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-app="main" ng-controller="stController">
            <div ng-include="'angularjs/src/include/main.htm'">
            </div>

            <div ng-include="'angularjs/src/include/subjects.htm'">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angularjs/src/module/mainApp.js"></script>
        <script src="angularjs/src/module/studentController.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` expects an angular expression evaluating to the URL

For example, if you write `ng-include="test.html"`, that would mean the html attribute of the test object of $scope.

When you say `ng-include="'test.html'"`, that is an angular expression. In this case, the string that evaluates to the value test.html

Here is the official documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation here,[ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), it says if string is a constant then you should use the single inverted commas, but for expressions like "getView()", "showViews()" etc, you don't need the single inverted commas